# Rename Multiple files with unknown/different names using powershell to same name

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I have a group of pictures (.jpg) all in the same folder that are all named something different. I am trying to rename all of them to the same name, numbered consecutively like it would in file explorer. EX. Test.jpg, Test(1).jpg Test(2) and so on.

This is what I have been trying but it tells me 'cannot create a file when that file already exists' and only changes the name of one file.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -newname { 'Test.jpg' }
```

I am hoping some could show me a way to get it to number them like above.
Thanks For All Help In Advance.

Comment: not **exactly** what you want but still doing the trick: `$i = 0 ; $x = gci . | % { $i++ ; Rename-Item $_ "Test($i).jpg" }` basically you loop over each file and for each loop you set `$i` + 1 and then use it in your `rename-item`

Comment: Well instead of simulating explorer behavior, you could [use explorer  ui](http://blog.backslasher.net/copying-files-in-powershell-using-windows-explorer-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this with a loop.

First you get the content of your folder and save that in a variable:

```
$Content = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\targetfolder"
```

Then, since you want to edit the whole content, you can use a "foreach" loop. And for the incrementing number just add a little integer variable to it. So something like this:

```
$n = 0

foreach($Content in $Content)
{
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\path\targetfolder\$Content" -NewName "test$n.jpg"
    $n++
}
```